# Вирусы на сайте

Tags: вирусы

Здравствуйте!На сайте обнаружен вредоносный код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Антивирусные программы ничего не находят. Яндекс вебмастер выводит такую картинку: 
[image]

Что делать? Сайт совсем простенький, даже БД не использует.
В коде js скриптов еще были прописаны ссылки на linkfooter.org на какой-то скрипт, но это всё я поудаляла уже.

Comment: на сервер файлы заливаем по ftp, ос - windows, антивирус есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым делом проверьте файл `catalog.php` на вредоносные ссылки и скрипты. Обычно их располагают в конце файла. Нашли - смело удаляйте. Также и с остальными файлами.

Вторым делом вам нужно будет сменить FTP пароли (или через какой протокол у вас происходит передача данных).

Если второе не сработало, то скорее всего уже на вашем компьютере вирус собирает пароли.

Comment: Спасибо. Вредоносных ссылок в файле нет.

Comment: ничего уже не понимаю, 2 года нормально работал сайт, а сейчас началось что-то непонятное, я уже этот скрипт (catalog.php) из копии восстановила и всё равно яндекс вебмастер выдает в результатах, что там вредоносный код.

Comment: может быть и копия заражена?

Comment: нет, копия старая и там всё чисто, там кода-то мало, антивирус на него не ругается, весь код мой

Comment: @Mariya а что отображается через ftp в зараженном файле? Там код присутствует? Я просто хочу понять, какое событие когда происходит.

Я понимаю так: вы заливаете чистый файл на сервер и он тут же становится плохим. По выводам можно судить о том, что ftp клиент добавляет к файлу. Но опять же - началось всё это внезапно, что тоже добавляет странность к ситуации.

Comment: нет, когда я просматриваю код этого скрипта прямо с фтп - то там тоже ничего плохого и странного не вижу

Comment: но вот яндекс и гугл никак не хотят считать его хорошим

Comment: Я бы посоветовал посмотреть этот файл постороннему человеку, чтобы убедиться, что это не ftp клиент такие чудеса вытворяет. Я, кстати, даже не знаю, говорю тут про вирусы, ftp, а может быть вы сидите через ssh с убунты?) Уточните.